# JavaScript - Distinguish between iOS and OSX through appVersion

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, operating-system, detection

I have an app that has a version for iOS and other for OSX (one in the App Store and one the Mac App Store). In our company website, I need to detect if the user is using iOS or OSX, so I can display a notification with a link to the app in the corresponding store. I'm using `navigator.appVersion` to detect the other OSs, is there any way to distinguish between iOS and OSX using `appVersion` or `userAgent` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. In OS X `navigator.userAgent` contains `"Mac OS X"`. For iOS it contains either `"iPhone"`, `"iPod"` or `"iPad"`.

So you can test for that using `indexOf` or regular expressions.